"Error in initializePtr(): function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package Matrix" gets displayed while trying to generate mixed effects model
I have already tried the previous solutions displayed by some users. I have tried removing and reinstalling Matrix and lme4 packages. To make matters worse, now R is unable to install lme4 or Matrix package. It says "Matrix package not available for this version of R". I have also tried the following command, which was given by some user:
tools::package_dependencies("Matrix", which = "LinkingTo", reverse = TRUE)
utils::install.packages("lme4", type = "source")

It displayed the same error and said unable to open the repository. It would be great if someone can help me sort this out.
I have tried the solutions previously posted. First I tried:
oo <- options(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")
utils::install.packages("Matrix")
utils::install.packages("lme4")
options(oo)

I got this reply:
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘Matrix’
2: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘Matrix’
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
  download from 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES' failed
Warning message:
package ‘Matrix’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 

Then I also tried another way:
remove.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("Matrix")
library(matrix)

remove.packages("Matrix")
remove.packages("lme4")
install.packages("lme4", type = "source")
library(lme4)

But each time, it just kept showing that it is unable to install Matrix for this version of R, hence it could not even install lme4, because lme4 requires Matrix package.

The important warning is this: Warning: unable to access index for repository .... This looks like a connection issue. Maybe a firewall or something is interfering.

As commented, this looks like a network error of some sort (this is problem #11 in this compendium of reasons for "package X is not available for this version of R"). See if you can download the relevant tarballs:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/Matrix_1.6-5.tgz
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/lme4_1.1-35.3.tgz

and install them locally (e.g. install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL), or through RStudio).
